# Do Phalanx Bowmen proc slow/freeze/stun on hit?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

When you have say 3% chance to freeze on hit, will enemies hit by Phalanx Bowmen get frozen? I'm mostly curious for interactions with Bane of the Trapped for enemies outside the slow radius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To calculate this, we need to know about a certain skill property that is commonly known as "Proc coefficient".

Each skill has this coefficient, which is a percentage between 0 and 100%. A value of 100% means, that on hit efffects (like stun on hit, freeze on hit, life on hit, etc) happen (proc) on each hit with full effectiveness / chance. So if you have a freeze chance of 3% and gain 10k life on hit, with a proc coefficient of 100% you will gain the full 10k life per hit and have a 3% chance to freeze.

A proc coefficient of 50% would mean, that your chance to stun on hit is halved <s>and life gained per hit is halved, too</s>. A value of 0 means, that nothing procs on hit.

This coefficient is mainly used to balance skills which can affect more than one enemy. [Source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Proc_Coefficient)

So, what's the proc rate of the Phalanx skill?

> - No Rune: 33.3%
> - Bowmen: -
> - Shield Charge: 33.3%
> - Stampede: 33.3%
> - Shield Bearers: 33.3%
> - Bodyguard: -

[Source](http://www.d3maxstats.com/skills/crus/)

So the answer is **no**, they will not get frozen by the bowmen.

**EDIT:** As of Patch 2.1, life on hit does not depend on the proc coefficient anymore. You either get the full amount on hit or you get nothing. You'll also get your life on hit only once per attack, no matter how many enemies you hit.

Comment: Those numbers are based on Patch 2.0.6, but I don't think they've changed since then.

Comment: I looked through the patch notes up to Patch 2.4 and yes, there were no changes to the proc coeffiecients of the Phalanx skill (they only changed once for the Punish skill). But I've found that my information on Life on Hit was wrong, I edited the answer to reflect this.